# How to seperate out a dataframe by ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, filter

I have a df which has object ID as the index, and then x values and y values in the columns, giving coordinates for where the object moved over time. For example:

```
id    x    y 
1    100  400
1    110  390
1    115  385
2    110  380
2    115  380
3    200  570
3    210  580
```

I would like to calculate the change in x and the change in y, for each object, so I can see direction (eg north-east) and how linear or how non linear each route is. I can then filter out object moving in a way I am not interested in.

How do I create a loop which loops over each object (aka ID) separately? For example trying something like: for len(df) would loop over the entire number of rows, it would not discriminate based on ID.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please show us, based on the sample provided, what the desired output would look like?

Comment: If there were appended to the above, a third and fourth column with "delta x" and "delta y", and then a fifth column with "direction" with a string. Or, some way to extract each object/id data, to plot on to a graph to determine degree of linearity in the coordinates over time. Essentially I just need a way to extract each set of coordinates for each ID separately, and not have python treat the whole dataframe as one object.

Comment: for example for the first object, it would be the first three set of x and y rows im interested in. Then once I reach object 2, it would be only rows five and six I want to find the difference for, not the last two or first two rows, which are objects 1 and 3 respectively

Comment: @jcat - What about using `groupby`?

Comment: How would this work in code? for example as an exercise to see if I could do something simpler (just add together all x according to id), i just tried df_group = df.groupby(['id']).sum('x') and the results were every column was added together, but separating by ID was indeed successful. The reason I thought to do it in a loop was because it would need to compare the x of a row to the x of row+1, as i want to track each change in direction over time.

Comment: "Loop Over" means you're approaching the issue completely wrong when it comes to pandas. Most attempts at manual iteration are inefficient at best, and outright wrong at worst. If `id` is really your index, that's not great either, since your index is supposed to be unique~

Comment: For your example there, I think you want what `df.groupby('id')['x'].sum()` gives~ @jcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# if id is your index, fix that:
df = df.reset_index()

# groupby id, getting the difference row by row within each group:
df[['chngX', 'chngY']] = df.groupby('id')[['x', 'y']].diff()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id    x    y  chngX  chngY
0   1  100  400    NaN    NaN
1   1  110  390   10.0  -10.0
2   1  115  385    5.0   -5.0
3   2  110  380    NaN    NaN
4   2  115  380    5.0    0.0
5   3  200  570    NaN    NaN
6   3  210  580   10.0   10.0
```

Comment: thank you, this seems right but I get the error: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Modified the code slightly to specify columns used~